# Xcode: Unable to run simulator error

Tags: xcode, swift, simulator

An error was encountered while running (Domain = NSMachErrorDomain, Code = -308)

That is the popup message I get every time. I found another question on here that had a bunch of solutions. I tried a dozen of them without much luck. After seeing the error message it will load the "Home" screen of the simulator but will have trouble running my app.

I made a new blank project and only added a text label to see if the error still happened with a next to blank app and it did.

Any ideas?

Comment: try to Reset Content and Settings of iOS Simulator and if it not work then Quit ios simulator and xcode and then try to run project..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the iOS Simulator and restore it by clicking on Reset Content and Settings.

[image]